# How to send SMS In C# MVC

Tags: c#

I've written some code to send SMS messages to employees.

All messages are saved in database. I'm fetching them from DB and passing the information in the uri, but when I get the response its showing "Empty text not allowed, rejected.".

Even if data is passed in the msgtext string variable, but after it executes the uri code, response is "Empty text not allowed, rejected."

```
var msgText = string.Empty;
var mobile = entities.LoginDetails
                     .FirstOrDefault(a=>a.EmployeeID==EMPID && a.Status==CrossCutting_Constants.Active)
                     .MobileNo;

var SMSContentSubject = entities.MASSMSGroups
                            .FirstOrDefault(a => a.ID == Contentid && a.Status == CrossCutting_Constants.Active);
if (mobile != null && mobile != string.Empty)
{
    msgText = SMSContentSubject.Content.Replace("EMPID", EMPID).Replace("EMPNAME", EMPNAME).ToString();
}
var requestUri = new Uri("http://www.myvaluefirst.com/smpp/sendsms" + "?username=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD&to=" + mobile + "&udh=0&from=MEDIMA&text=" + msgText + "&dlr-url=");

var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
var response = webRequest.GetResponse();
var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
var streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
var text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: it says "Empty text not allowed" and you are setting `msgText` to  `string.Empty`

Comment: Please give us some more details: Which SMS Gateway do you use? Also this has a flaw, apparently you are sending the Password in cleartext.

Comment: I'm sorry you are having trouble, however this question is a poor fit for SO.  I recommend you read the documentation provided by your SMS gateway, and possibly employ some rudimentary debugging skills.

Comment: are you sure that mobile is not null? , maybe you want to extend that if(mobile ...)  to cover the whole "send code" and not just the setting of msgText

Comment: But in msgtext data is coming in if condition,after that only we are passing it to uri.

Comment: Yes i am getting both mobile and msgtext value and its visible in (Uri request )if u trace the code,but at the end  string text = streamReader.ReadToEnd(); giving "Empty text".

Comment: Please include an example of msgText

Comment: My msgtext content "445454545 Wish u Happy Married life kiran01 Kumta" and mobile content "+918546914681"

Comment: I think you need to URL encode your parameters, e.g. the `to` parameter should start with `%2B` not `+`.

Comment: My uri response is "http://www.myvaluefirst.com/smpp/sendsms?username=medimanagecri&password=medimib2&to=+918546914681&udh=0&from=MEDIMA&text=445454545%20Wish%20u%20Happy%20Married%20life%20kiran01%20Kumta&dlr-url="

Comment: Some times i am getting string text value (check code) "Invalid Template"

Comment: Maybe this comment it is offtopic, but it drives me crazy, when someone uses `C# MVC`. What the hell is this? Do you mean using ASP.NET MVC or desktop application which is built in MVC approach or what? To be clear, I understand that this question is about ASP.NET MVC, which doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

@Niyaz : You should place an if condition around msgText

```
//Do not send sms, if sms content is empty.


  if (mobile != null && mobile != string.Empty)
    {
        msgText = SMSContentSubject.Content.Replace("EMPID", EMPID).Replace("EMPNAME", EMPNAME).ToString();

        If(!string.IsNullorEmpty(msgText))
        {
      String myEncodedString;
         // Encode the string.
         myEncodedString = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(msgText );

            Uri requestUri = new Uri("http://www.myvaluefirst.com/smpp/sendsms" + "?username=medimanagecri&password=medimib2&to=" + mobile + "&udh=0&from=MEDIMA&text=" + myEncodedString + "&dlr-url=");
            WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
            WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse();
            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
            string text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```

Comment: i tried this one but still same result in string text "Empty text not allowed,rejected"

Comment: Does the SMS Vendor accepts GET or POST or PUT
Currently you are doing a GET...
Check the SMS Content size specification from Vendor too. Do you need to trim that ?

Comment: No need to trim it because if content is lagre it will send 2 sms. i treid this also but still same result

Comment: Do a proof of concept first: Try to hardcode 
//Dummy data
msgText = "I want to send sms";

try to send the sms with above string value.

Comment: The Message should be URL Encoded.
follow the link here.

Documentation for your Vendor: http://www.libertylighting.in/uploads/docfe5dbbcea5ce7e2988b8c69bcfdfde8904aabc1f.PDF

You can test sample code by encoding text here: http://www.url-encode-decode.com/

Comment: I added your given string and tried but still same result. for the same code i taken value from crosscutting it works but not working with my DB data.

Comment: Update your question with text message, exact message after encoded.

Comment: Before:::http://www.myvaluefirst.com/smpp/sendsms?username=medimanagecri&password=medimib2&to=+918546914681&udh=0&from=MEDIMA&text=Wish%20u%20happy%20birth%20day&dlr-url=

Comment: You said "for the same code i taken value from crosscutting it works". Can you provide an example URL that *does* work?